# Error - This command can only be run inside of a CLI project

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am working on an ionic 3 project with the name portal. I need to create a service called user but i keep getting the above error.
These are the steps i followed:

```
cd portal 
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
npm install
ng g service user
```

Then i get the error *This command can only be run inside of a CLI project*. 
I noticed that angular-cli is not getting added to my dependency list in package.json nor do i have the cli directory under @angular in the node modules directory.
I tried the install angular-cli twice but the error persists. Have been stuck with it for a long time any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Have you created your app? ng new your_app_name? You might be running this command outside the angular cli project directory. You must be in the same directory path where your angular cli json is present.

Comment: yep created the app.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: i created it in the beginning. This error is existing after that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok let me, instead of commenting, write an answer.

The error occurs because you're using the Angular CLI in a project which isn't generated by the Angular CLI, thus missing configuration files.

Since you're stating that you have an ionic 3 application, you don't need the angular CLI.

Step 1: create project (you probably have done this one)

```
ionic start portal blank
```

Step 2: go into your project

```
cd portal
```

Step 3: (npm install is already done, just generate a service)

```
ionic generate provider user
```

Comment: You saved the day. :)

Comment: I just have one more question. Providers and services will serve the same purpose? Or i need to modify some things to get my work done?

Comment: I'm not quite sure because I don't use the ionic cli myself. Although since `services` are injected into the NgModule's `providers` args, I suppose they're the same. Just the difference that ionic chose a different name

Answer (score 3):

Your steps must be in this order:

1) Install angular globally

```
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

2) Create the app at a directory location

```
ng new portal
```

3) Go into that folder

```
cd .\portal\
```

4) Install node modules

```
npm install
```

5) Generate service

```
ng g service user
```

If your commands are not in this order, you will have an error.

Comment: When I created the ionic project I used "ionic start myapp blank" which is the command of creating a new ionic project. Do I need to again use "ng new portal"?

Comment: So did it created a folder? You need to go inside that folder then.

Comment: Yes it created a folder - portal. I will try these set of commands inside the portal folder.

Comment: @rinisaha for ionic projects, check out the ionic CLI documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/

Comment: @Ivaro18 Does "the cli project" in the error refers to ionic cli or angular cli? Because all the answers regarding this question on stack overflow refers to angular cli.

Comment: Your error seems to be from `ng g service user`, this totally depends on how you created your project but if you started `ionic start portal` you should run `ionic generate provider user` instead of using the Angular CLI. The above answer will provide you with an Angular project instead of an ionic project