# Getting error "This command can only be run inside of a CLI project error while running through CLI"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

[image]

I am working on existing angular and .Net MVC application. In Web Project, I used angular and HTML pages. I want to run this application through CLI. II try to use ng serve option but it's giving above error.

I used following steps to run. Please let me know If anything is missing

1)Open Cmd prompt and went to my web project folder in which angular and package.json exist. 2)run ng serve --open in that location

getting above mentioned error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50577261/5043867

Comment: Please explain more, Is it one project? If it is, then how did you create it? Is it a .net application containing angular code for views?

Comment: @mmushtaq : please see now

Comment: @Pardeep jain Please see folder structure

Answer (score 1):

I hope your project is a demo, because it is incorrectly managed, your `app` folder should be inside `src` folder. For using Visual Studio to make Angular App.

Here is a video tutorial/playlist to follow.
[Setting up Angular 2 in Visual Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9iK2Eib85E&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWqGD8BuKuX-VTKqlNBj-m6&index=2) . Here, you will see correct architecture to keep your files/folders, and method to run your application. Although, it is not my recommendation.

**1). Recommendation =>**   Use VS Code for making Angular App, and .Net Core for making Web API. For making http calls, you will have CORS at your service. Following this architecture will keep your application well-maintained.

***OR***

**2). Recommendation =>**   If You want to use Visual Studio for both sides, make .Net Core Web Application, there you will find ANGULAR, make project from there, and compare its architecture with your own.

Comment: Still have same issue.I have demo solution AngularApp in that I have web project named as AngularAPP and in web project I have angular folder called as app.

Comment: Share a snapshot image of the hierarchy in VS Code or similar application. It will help in understanding your naming schemes, because your angular folder `app` should be inside `src` folder, not AngularAPP folder

Comment: Yeah Shared screenshot of the project structure

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar123456, Please, accept as solution, if correct. And delete irrelevant previous comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to go inside the Angular CLI project directory to run this command.
(Probably where your `package.json` file exist)

Comment: I gave the path of that project only

Comment: Just go into that folder and run the same command , project will run like a charm

Comment: :- I tried but still not working. Mentioned steps in description through which I went. Please guide me if anything I missed